# Parentheses in string of javascript function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, parentheses

I have a loop that creates links with a javascript function call in the onClick events and uses the text returned from a database as one of the parameters.  My issues I am having is that sometimes this text being returned has parenthesis in them which is causing a syntax error in my code. 
Example:

```
code:
formResults += "<a onclick='openForm(" + this.displayText + "," + this.ID + ");'>" + this.displayText + "</a>";

HTMLDisplay:
<a onclick="openForm(Example Form (Example Form 1) Application Instructions ,1108);">Example Form (Example Form 1) Application Instructions </a>
```

as you can see the name of the form contains a set of parenthesis.  Is there anyway I can include these?  The reason I need to is because the function points to another system that uses the ID and displayText in order to render the proper form.
thank you

Comment: Don't do that.  Use `addEventListener`

Comment: If you give us a wider context here for what this code is doing, we might be able to suggest better solutions that don't require the construction of complicated strings that are a combination of HTML and Javascript which is generally a mess to read (and as you have discovered) a mess to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parenthesis aren't the problem, it's the lack of quotes inside the function.

```
formResults += "<a onclick='openForm(\'" + this.displayText + "," + this.ID + "\');'>" + this.displayText + "</a>";
```

This below snippet (from yours)

```
`openForm(Example Form...`)
```

Will throw an error because it's looking for variables `Example` and so on, quote that string!

Comment: that is a rookie mistake on my part for sure, thank you all for your help on this, i'll make as answer when i can in a few minutes! works great

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest

code:

```
formResults += '<a class="openForm" data-text="'+this.displayText + '" id="'+this.ID + '">' + this.displayText + '</a>';
```

HTMLDisplay:

```
<a class="openForm" data-text="Example Form (Example Form 1) Application Instructions" id="1108">Example Form (Example Form 1) Application Instructions </a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".openForm").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    openForm($(this).data("text"),this.id);
  });
});
```